# How can I get the IP address of a network printer given the port name using the Win32 API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, printing

How can I get the IP address of a network printer given the port name, 
using win32 API?

I tried looking into the `PRINTER_INFO_* structs`, but it seems it is not present there.

Comment: Is this possible? How can u get it just with the port number.

Comment: Good question - perhaps be more explicit with what you mean by port name?

Comment: @Shoban : Not port number but port name.
@Elemental : port name is something you need to give while configuring printer port in "Printers and Faxes". You can get port name of all printers using ::EnumPrinter win32 API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a standard way to get the IP address.  There are probably different incompatible implementations of network port monitors.  For my network printer, the IP address is part of the port name (e.g., `IP_192_168.1.104`).  If it's of that form, then you might be able to parse it out, but I don't think this is universal.

Using `EnumPorts` you can determine if it's a network printer, but I still don't see a way to get the IP address.

Comment: The port name can be edited after it was created, there is no guarantee that "IP_192_168.1.104" is actually 192.168.1.104.  You can get the IP address for the port name through WMI with the WQL query of "Select Name, HostAddress from Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort"

Comment: As Adrian says there is no way to get this through the APIs. The only means is by reading the registry on the print server under the key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports

Answer (score 4):

you can get the port name by PRINTER_INFO_2,and the get the ip from the registry,the path is:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Monitors\Standard TCP/IP Port\Ports
the ip store in "HostName"

Answer (score 2):

Like any other IP network device, the printer will have an IP address (denoting it's ethernet card), and will run a service on a certain port (identifying the program responding to printer messages).  This is merely networking stuff and has nothing yet to do with printer specific stuff.

So given it's port only, there's no way to find it's IP address.  Probably the services on all the other printers listen to the same port.

Assuming you mean you have the printer's name, you need to query the name service for your domain.  This service maps network addresses to 'symbolic' names.

Using the winsock2 api, I believe it's [`gethostbyname`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738524(VS.85).aspx) you need.  This will retrieve the host info of your printer by it's name.

Comment: There are multiple meanings to the word 'port' in the context of this question.  I don't think the poster was referring to the port that the printer's service is listening on.  Windows tracks printers by name and port (e.g., port might be `LPT1:`).  In newer versions of the API, the port name is rarely needed.

Answer (score 1):

I came looking for an answer but didn't really accept there was no way and found that there actually is.  This answer is in Delphi, but it's pretty straightforward:

```
function PortIPAddress(Port: string): string;
var
  buf:          PWideChar;
  pd:           PRINTER_DEFAULTS;
  c,
  d,
  bs,
  hXcv:         cardinal;
begin
  Result := 'unknown';

  ZeroMemory(@pd, SizeOf(PRINTER_DEFAULTS));
  pd.DesiredAccess := SERVER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER;

  if OpenPrinter(PAnsiChar(Format(',XcvPort %s', [Port])), hXcv, @pd) then
  begin
    XcvData(hXcv, 'IPAddress', nil, 0, nil, 0, @bs, @c);

    GetMem(buf, bs);
    try
      if XcvData(hXcv, 'IPAddress', nil, 0, buf, bs, @d, @c) then
        Result := buf;
    finally
      FreeMem(buf, bs);
    end;
  end;

  ClosePrinter(hXcv);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use Advanced Printer apis, dynamic call