# how to get PRINTER's IP using windows API in c++?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to get the printer's (Network printer) IP address, I have tried to get it from WMI queries and looked in Registry, but I couldn't find it anywhere.
Is there any windows API to get the IP address of the printer?
NOTE:I have seen this URL.
[How can I get the IP address of a network printer given the port name using the Win32 API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587716/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-a-network-printer-given-the-port-name-using-the)

Comment: What information do you have? Printer name. Printer port.

Comment: i have the printer portname(WSD-21d5a02e-75d4-44f0-8c07-a75d31fa75f5.0032) and printer name(EPSONF91EC2 (L550 Series)) from PRINTER_INFO_2 structure.